# Watson NLU never returns disambiguation info

Tags: ibm-cloud, dbpedia, watson-conversation, watson, watson-nlu

I'm trying to use a combination of Watson conversation and Watson NLU to extract entities and compare them to a list. I need access to the disambiguation information returned, but its not returning for anything I put in.

It is correctly extracting the companies, places, people etc as entities, and the correct categorisation. But none of the entities have the disambiguation info. Is there something i'm missing? all of the entities have dbpedia entries (i've checked manually).

e.g.

```
"entities": [
    {
      "type": "Organization",
      "text": "NHS",
      "sentiment": {
        "score": 0,
        "label": "neutral"
      },
      "relevance": 0.949001,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "type": "Company",
      "text": "IBM",
      "sentiment": {
        "score": 0.497916,
        "label": "positive"
      },
      "relevance": 0.643598,
      "count": 1
    }
  ],
```

**Update:**
I tried typing in `CNN` like the example in the [API doc](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/#entities) and that works:

```
"entities": [
    {
      "type": "Company",
      "text": "CNN",
      "sentiment": {
        "score": 0,
        "label": "neutral"
      },
      "relevance": 0.33,
      "disambiguation": {
        "subtype": [
          "Broadcast",
          "AwardWinner",
          "RadioNetwork",
          "TVNetwork"
        ],
        "name": "CNN",
        "dbpedia_resource": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/CNN"
      },
      "count": 1
    }
  ],
```

but nothing else is. Does it only work for a small subset of entities?

Comment: Which example are you referencing that was successful? Please provide a link. Also, please post relevant parts of your code.

Comment: @JonathanM I meant I tried typing in some text that included the word `CNN` like the example in the API docs. That successfully returned the disambiguation info, but the above examples did not

Comment: Hmmm. Can you add what your curl request and json look like?

Comment: I seem to get some disambiguation with other companies like Microsoft or Google. I'm not sure what's the date of the dpbedia dataset that is used for NLU.

Comment: @JonathanM all i'm doing is using the watson developer cloud node.js sdk and passing in `{sentiment:{}, emotion:{}, categories:{}, keywords:{sentiment: true}, entities:{sentiment: true}}` to the features param. Unlikely its my code as well if its working for `CNN`. Just tried the [NLU demo](https://natural-language-understanding-demo.ng.bluemix.net/) and its the same results. Can't get full results for anything other than `CNN`, which is very frustrating

Comment: Yeah, I'm not saying it's your code, but there are helpful things, differences, etc. that become visible when code is shared.

Answer (score 0):

I tried sending the following body in a request

```
{
    "text":"IBM is a company based in Newyork",
    "features": {
    "entities":{}}
}
```

It returns the output with disambiguation info.

```
{
"usage": {
    "text_units": 1,
    "text_characters": 33,
    "features": 1
},
"language": "en",
"entities": [
{
    "type": "Company",
    "text": "IBM",
    "relevance": 0.33,
    "disambiguation": {
        "subtype": [
            "SoftwareLicense",
            "OperatingSystemDeveloper",
            "ProcessorManufacturer",
            "SoftwareDeveloper",
            "CompanyFounder",
            "ProgrammingLanguageDesigner",
            "ProgrammingLanguageDeveloper"
        ],
        "name": "IBM",
        "dbpedia_resource": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/IBM"
    },
    "count": 2
},
{
    "type": "Location",
    "text": "Newyork",
    "relevance": 0.33,
    "disambiguation": {
        "subtype": [
            "City"
        ]
    },
    "count": 1
}
]
}
```

Having said that, it does return the DBpedia URI's for the most of the entries in DBpedia.If you are still unable to get the disambig info with DBpedia URI, post the request text you are sending as a comment.

Comment: sorry for the delay getting back, had to leave my computer. Tried the NLU online demo again and it works under circumstances where there is additional text to explain the entity. e.g. "test to see what comes up for IBM the technology company" works fine, but "test to see what comes up for IBM" doesn't, but it still manages to extract the entity for IBM which is confusing because it matches a DBpedia entry exactly. In my current use case its unlikely someone will enter text like the first sample. Guess i'll have to play around with the dbpedia API to see can I find the info if none is available

Comment: Yeah, what you said is correct, it needs some context around the entity to figure out the disambiguation information. It correctly extracts the entity information because it uses a combination of entity taggers which work with context and without context. But whereas for Disambiguation, context is the key.